# How to show tooltip for IntegerUpdown control?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf, integerupdown

I try to make tooltip on DevExpress `IntegerUpDown` (`DoubleUpDown` and so on) control:

```
  <xcd:DoubleUpDown
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Margin="5,2" 
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Minimum="0"                                                            
                          Value="{Binding SomeValue,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                          Text="{Binding SomeValue,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                          ToolTip="{Binding SomeValue,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                            >                         
                        </xcd:DoubleUpDown>
```

But, it do not work for me - only empty tooltip shows.
How to make tooltip?

Comment: The binding probably doesn't work. And why are you setting the Mode to TwoWay? Makes no sense. What's the DataContext of the control?

Comment: @mm8, binding works for all controls (like TextBox), except DevEpress controls. I set programmatically:  ratedPowerUpDown.DataContext = DataContext;  but no effect

Comment: DevExpress Controls? If you set the Tooltip to a hard-coded value it should work: ToolTip="...". Then you know that the binding fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you see an empty `ToolTip` at runtime, it is your binding that fails.

Try to set the `ToolTip` property to a hard-coded value and you should see that it works:

```
ToolTip="Test"
```

You then know that there is something wrong with your binding. Make sure that the `DoubleUpDown` control has a `DataContext` that has a `public` `SomeValue` property that returns the value you are expecting to show up in the tooltip.

Also note that it makes no sense to set the `Mode` property to `TwoWay` and the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to `PropertyChanged` on a `ToolTip` binding.